# Class imbalance for binary classification in keras

Tags: keras

I am doing binary classification. My y_train is like [0,1,1,0,0]. It is one dimensional. I am using sigmoid as activation in the final layer and also only 1 output neuron in last layer. I can use class_weight.compute_class_weight to find class weights from y_train and then feed it to class_weight parameter in keras.fit function. Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should work. The class weight is a map that indicates relative weight between classes and is considered when weighing samples results during training.

Comment: Will it be fine if I convert y into one_hot encoding and then give weights by using softmax in final layer and also categorical crossentropy. I know for sure that this works since class_weights works for multi class classification?

Comment: If you have binary classification, one hot encoding and softmax are overkill. You can just approach the problem as originally stated.